# Опции select class

Tags: php

В чем весь сабж.Как видно на фото есть 1 вариант и два свойства.(извиняюсь за оформление)
[image]

На сайте они отображаются так

[image]

вот код

```
    <form class="variants" action="/cart">



                    <select name="variant1" {if $product->variants|count==1  && !$product->variant->name1}style='display:none;'{/if}>
            {foreach $product->variants as $v}
            <option value="{$v->id}" {if $v->compare_price > 0}compare_price="{$v->compare_price|convert}"{/if} price="{$v->price|convert}">
            {$v->name1}
            </option>
            {/foreach}
        </select>

                    <select name="variant2" {if $product->variants|count==1  && !$product->variant->name2}style='display:none;'{/if}>
            {foreach $product->variants as $v}
            <option value="{$v->id}" {if $v->compare_price > 0}compare_price="{$v->compare_price|convert}"{/if} price="{$v->price|convert}">
            {$v->name2}
            </option>
            {/foreach}
        </select>



        <div class="price">
            <strike>
            {if $product->variant->compare_price > 0}
            {$product->variant->compare_price|convert}
            {/if}
            </strike>
            <span>{$product->variant->price|convert}</span>
            <i>{$currency->sign|escape}</i>
        </div>



        <input type="submit" class="button" value="в корзину" data-result-text="добавлено"/>
    </form>
    <!-- Выбор варианта товара (The End) -->
```

Нужно сделать чтобы было как тут [клац](http://simpla.byethost17.com/products/samsung-s5570-galaxy-mini)

я убрал variant name 1...и вроде бы все хорошо...но есть одно НО...если выбираешь первый "КРАСНЫЙ" и первый "35"-все хорошо....но чтобы выбрать 36 красный.нужно обязательно выбрать "красный" второй и "36" второй....скажите как  сделать так чтобы не было повторяющихся вариантов и в корзину все отправлялось без ошибок

Comment: вы в курсе, что у вас не пхп код а темплейт ? почему-бы не указать какой именно движек темплейтный используется. Там где **клац** там на jquery сделано.

Comment: Может лучше сделать, чтобы был только один выпадающий список **Название варианта** ? Если бы я зашел на сайт купить телефон, то мне так было бы удобнее, потому что сразу видны возможные варианты независимо ни от чего (может вариант 36 не существует синий, или есть вариант 37 только розовый).  
П.С. Это личное мнение, оно не выражает мнение большинства.

Comment: движок simpla...а о том как лучше....лучше сжечь создателя движка...нету другой возможности оформления модуля....ну а если там на jquery...то как сделать так же?

Comment: аууу.подскажет кто нибудь решение или нет?

Comment: ага, скопируйте "оттуда", никто не подорвется учить simpla за вас.

Comment: Вопрос закрыт

Comment: @HoPkInS, поделитесь решением ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Так](http://jsfiddle.net/u2sVe/) подойдет?

Comment: Не прошло и года...всеровно спасибо)